# COUNT DISTINCT with CONDITIONS

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of distinct items in a column subject to a certain condition, for example if the table is like this:

```
tag | entryID
----+---------
foo | 0
foo | 0
bar | 3
```

If I want to count the number of distinct tags as "tag count" and count the number of distinct tags with entry id > 0 as "positive tag count" in the same table, what should I do?

I'm now counting from two different tables where in the second table I've only selected those rows with entryID larger than zero. I think there should be a more compact way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select
  count(distinct tag) as tag_count,
  count(distinct (case when entryId > 0 then tag end)) as positive_tag_count
from
  your_table_name;
```

The first `count(distinct...)` is easy.
The second one, looks somewhat complex, is actually the same as the first one, except that you use `case...when` clause. In the `case...when` clause, you filter only positive values. Zeros or negative values would be evaluated as `null` and won't be included in count.

One thing to note here is that this can be done by reading the table once. When it seems that you have to read the same table twice or more, it can actually be done by reading once, in most of the time. As a result, it will finish the task a lot faster with less I/O.

Comment: But then will positive_tag_count be distinct as well?

Comment: The edited query still does not solve the problem - isn't this now working on distinct entryId values rather than distinct tags?

Comment: I have multiple columns in my distinct (example count(distinct tag, date)). Is there a way to have multiple columns in the then clause. If i just do a tag,date it throws a parse exception

Comment: @Crusaderpyro That is beyond the scope of the original question. I'd create a new question for that.

Comment: Note that in standard SQL, you can also write the second expression as `count(distinct tag) filter (where entryId > 0)`

Comment: Might want to subtract 1, because SQL will count all failed conditions as 1 distinct counting group

Comment: @Crusaderpyro This is more of a hack, but you could use CONCAT(COLUMN1, COLUMN2) in the then clause for this solution to still work.

Comment: How to do the same SQL code above in Linq

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
SELECT Count(tag) AS 'Tag Count'
FROM Table
GROUP BY tag
```

and

```
SELECT Count(tag) AS 'Negative Tag Count'
FROM Table
WHERE entryID > 0
GROUP BY tag
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following statement:

```
select  distinct A.[Tag],
     count(A.[Tag]) as TAG_COUNT,
     (SELECT count(*) FROM [TagTbl] AS B WHERE A.[Tag]=B.[Tag] AND B.[ID]>0)
     from [TagTbl] AS A GROUP BY A.[Tag]
```

The first field will be the tag the second will be the whole count the third will be the positive ones count.

Answer (score 2):

Code counts the unique/distinct combination of Tag & Entry ID when [Entry Id]>0

```sql
select count(distinct(concat(tag,entryId)))
from customers
where id>0
```

In the output it will display the count of unique values
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @ntalbs solution,
if you want to count a column's data when the condition of another column's data is valid, you can do this

```
select
  count(distinct tag) as tag_count,
  count(distinct tag, case when entryId > 0 then tag end) as positive_tag_count
from
  your_table_name;
```

On line 3, I added the column name beside the `distinct`, so it will count the distinct tags when the entryId is greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

This may also work:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT T.tag) as DistinctTag,
    COUNT(DISTINCT T2.tag) as DistinctPositiveTag
FROM Table T
    LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T.tag = T2.tag AND T.entryID = T2.entryID AND T2.entryID > 0
```

You need the entryID condition in the left join rather than in a where clause in order to make sure that any items that only have a entryID of 0 get properly counted in the first DISTINCT.

Comment: This query reads the table twice. It can be done by reading the table only once.