# Mysql SUM CASE with unique IDs only

Tags: mysql, sum, case

Easiest explained through an example.

A father has children who win races.

How many of a fathers offspring have won a race and how many races in total have a fathers offspring won. (winners and wins)

I can easily figure out the total amount of wins but sometimes a child wins more than one race so to figure out winners I need only sum if the child has won, not all the times it has won.

In the below extract from a query I cannot use Distinct, so this doesn't work

```
SUM(CASE WHEN r.finish = '1' AND DISTINCT h.runnersid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS winners,
```

This also won't work

```
SUM(SELECT DISTINCT r.runnersid FROM runs r WHERE r.finish='1') AS winners
```

This works when I need to find the total amount of wins.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN r.finish = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS wins,
```

Here is a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9a81/1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: this question is actually quite fun to read :)

Comment: I was in a similar spot and that helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048098/count-distinct-with-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this step by step.

You have two pieces of information you are looking for: Who has won a race, and how many races have they one.

Taking the first one, you can select a distinct runnersid where they have a first place finish:

```
SELECT DISTINCT runnersid 
FROM runs
WHERE finish = 1;
```

For the second one, you can select every runnersid where they have a first place finish, count the number of rows returned, and group by runnersid to get the total wins for each:

```
SELECT runnersid, COUNT(*) AS numWins
FROM runs
WHERE finish = 1
GROUP BY runnersid;
```

The second one actually has everything you want. You don't need to do anything with that first query, but I used it to help demonstrate the thought process I take when trying to accomplish a task like this.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fda5f/3) example.

**EDIT**

As you've seen, you don't really need the SUM here. Because finish represents a place in the race, you don't want to SUM that value, but you want to COUNT the number of wins.

**EDIT2**

An additional edit based on OPs requirements. The above does not match what OP needs, but I left this in as a reference to any future readers. What OP really needs, as I understand it now, is the number of children each father has that has run a race. I will again explain my thought process step by step.

First I wrote a simple query that pulls all of the winning father-son pairs. I was able to use GROUP BY to get the distinct winning pairs:

```
SELECT father, name
FROM runs
WHERE finish = 1
GROUP BY father, name;
```

Once I had done that, I used it is a subquery and the COUNT(*) function to get the number of winners for each father (this means I have to group by father):

```
SELECT father, COUNT(*) AS numWinningChildren
FROM(SELECT father, name
      FROM runs
      WHERE finish = 1
      GROUP BY father, name) t
GROUP BY father;
```

If you just need the fathers with winning children, you are done. If you want to see all fathers, I would write one query to select all fathers, join it with our result set above, and replace any values where `numWinningChildren` is null, with 0.

I'll leave that part to you to challenge yourself a bit. Also because SQL Fiddle is down at the moment and I can't test what I was thinking, but I was able to test those above with success.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question, see my sqlfiddle.

Comment: @stemie I will look into it this afternoon when I'm off work. Sorry for misunderstanding. If you solve this before then, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the father name along with the count of the wins by his sons.

```
select father, count(distinct(id)) wins 
from runs where father = 'jack' and finish = 1
group by father
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73c91/9)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for

`Select user_id, sum(case when finish='1' then 1 else 0 end) as total
From table
Group by user_id`

Comment: I can work that one out `SUM(CASE WHEN r.finish = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS wins` I need to find winners so only if a child has won not how many times they have won.