# Nested Select with Count Distinct and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, nested

So I'm trying to get 2 sets or results from the same table grouped by a 3rd column, it's best i let my example explain;

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
  FROM Database
    WHERE Status NOT LIKE 'closed') AS ColumnA,

  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
  FROM Database
    WHERE Status NOT LIKE 'closed' AND Datevalue <= getdate()) AS ColumnB

Group By ColumnC
```

Now I know this wont/doesn't work but it explains what I want. If I leave the group by out then i get the figures as a whole but i want them grouping by another Column.

Mind is melting, ready to be enlightened.

Comment: This answer might be more along the lines of what you're looking for as opposed to nesting `SELECT` statements you can do a `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` with conditionals [sql- COUNT DISTINCT with CONDITION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048098/count-distinct-with-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select columnC,
       count(distinct case when Status <> 'closed' then id end) as columnA,
       count(distinct case when Status <> 'closed' and datevalue <= getdate() then id end) as columnb
from database  -- a very curious name for a table
group by ColumnC;
```

Comment: You sir, are a savour, I've been banging my head for close to an hour. thank you! I shall now study this to ensure i understand it for future use. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT ColumnC,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Status NOT LIKE 'closed' THEN id END) as  ColumnA,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Status NOT LIKE 'closed' AND  Datevalue <= getdate() THEN id END) as  ColumnB
    FROM mydatabase
    GROUP BY ColumnC
```