# COUNT DISTINCT on multiple columns with Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a count on distinct of multiple columns with case condition
I already know the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048098/count-distinct-with-conditions/14048147#14048147) if I have just 1 column. But if I have multiple columns as follows:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN CustomerId > 10 THEN CITY,COUNTRY END))
    FROM Customers;
```

The error I get is

```
Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near ",": syntax error)
```

Comment: Your query does not make sense. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah it was not supposed to be a sensible query as I cannot copy paste the actual sensitive column and table data. I just wanted to use multiple columns in the Then clause of the distinct

Comment: Use it for what? Count them how?? Or do you want to sum them?

Comment: Your case statement try to return two column `THEN CITY,COUNTRY END` which, AFAIK isn't accepted. You need to use a work around for that. Either duplicate the case, on for each cit or simply use a `where` condition and a group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your columns are but you could always just group.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1), 
  concat(CITY, ",", COUNTRY) as location 
FROM Customers where CustomerId > 10 
GROUP BY location
```

Basically this will count the number of 1's for each unique combination of CITY and COUNTRY.

Also, if you wanted to count distinct locations, just concat in the CASE THEN clause

```
SELECT COUNT(
  DISTINCT (CASE WHEN CustomerId > 10 
    THEN CONCAT(CITY,",",COUNTRY) END)
  ) 
FROM Customers;
```

Your "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near ",": syntax error)" arises because the THEN CLAUSE expects 1 arg without a comma

Comment: Yes. Edited the answer.

Comment: Also note that your count will be off by 1. This is because your case statement will result in a null when the CustomerId <= 10

Comment: That is ok.. the query in the question was jsut a sample data and not the actual columns